# QBO PHP Getting field of multi dimension

Tags: php, arrays

This seems so simple, but I just want to echo this and I can't seem to figure out how to access the second part of the array.  BillAddr is the first part and Line1 is the second part.  It return nothing even though that feild has data

```
$Customer = $dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE DisplayName='$anthonysname'");        
echo "the given address line 1 is:" . $Customer->BillAddr[Line1] . "<br><br><br>";      
//BillAddr/Line1
```

This is the array scheme

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPCustomer)#59 (72) { ["Taxable"]=> string(4) "true" ["BillAddr"]=> object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPhysicalAddress)#90 (16) { ["Id"]=> string(4) "1163" ["Line1"]=> string(36) "​3415 dhfjdf Pike, Suite 301" ["Line2"]=> NULL ["Line3"]=> NULL ["Line4"]=> NULL ["Line5"]=> NULL ["City"]=> string(14) "Newtown Square" ["Country"]=> NULL ["CountryCode"]=> NULL ["CountrySubDivisionCode"]=> string(2) "PA" ["PostalCode"]=> string(5) "19073" ["PostalCodeSuffix"]=> NULL ["Lat"]=> NULL ["Long"]=> NULL ["Tag"]=> NULL ["Note"]=> NULL } ["ShipAddr"]=> NULL ["OtherAddr"]=> NULL ["ContactName"]=> NULL ["AltContactName"]=> NULL ["Notes"]=> NULL ["Job"]=> string(5) "false" ["BillWithParent"]=> string(5) "false" ["RootCustomerRef"]=> NULL ["ParentRef"]=> NULL ["Level"]=> NULL ["CustomerTypeRef"]=> NULL ["SalesTermRef"]=> string(1) "3" ["SalesRepRef"]=> NULL ["TaxGroupCodeRef"]=> NULL ["TaxRateRef"]=> NULL ["PaymentMethodRef"]=> NULL ["CCDetail"]=> NULL ["PriceLevelRef"]=> NULL ["Balance"]=> string(1) "0" ["OpenBalanceDate"]=> NULL ["BalanceWithJobs"]=> string(6) "182.85" ["CreditLimit"]=> NULL ["AcctNum"]=> NULL ["CurrencyRef"]=> string(3) "USD" ["OverDueBalance"]=> NULL ["TotalRevenue"]=> NULL ["TotalExpense"]=> NULL ["PreferredDeliveryMethod"]=> string(4) "None" ["ResaleNum"]=> NULL ["JobInfo"]=> NULL ["TDSEnabled"]=> NULL ["CustomerEx"]=> NULL ["SecondaryTaxIdentifier"]=> NULL ["ARAccountRef"]=> NULL ["PrimaryTaxIdentifier"]=> NULL ["TaxExemptionReasonId"]=> NULL ["IsProject"]=> string(5) "false" ["BusinessNumber"]=> NULL ["GSTIN"]=> NULL ["GSTRegistrationType"]=> NULL ["IsCISContractor"]=> NULL ["IntuitId"]=> NULL ["Organization"]=> NULL ["Title"]=> NULL ["GivenName"]=> NULL ["MiddleName"]=> NULL ["FamilyName"]=> NULL ["Suffix"]=> NULL ["FullyQualifiedName"]=> string(39) "American National Facilities Management" ["CompanyName"]=> string(39) "Asdfdsfdsft" ["DisplayName"]=> string(39) "Adsfdsfds" ["PrintOnCheckName"]=> string(39) "fgdfghfdjkghfdjkgh" ["UserId"]=> NULL ["Active"]=> string(4) "true" ["PrimaryPhone"]=> object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPTelephoneNumber)#88 (9) { ["Id"]=> NULL ["DeviceType"]=> NULL ["CountryCode"]=> NULL ["AreaCode"]=> NULL ["ExchangeCode"]=> NULL ["Extension"]=> NULL ["FreeFormNumber"]=> string(12) "555-555-5555" ["Default"]=> NULL ["Tag"]=> NULL } ["AlternatePhone"]=> NULL ["Mobile"]=> NULL ["Fax"]=> NULL ["PrimaryEmailAddr"]=> object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPEmailAddress)#91 (4) { ["Id"]=> NULL ["Address"]=> string(25) "serivice@anfmservices.com" ["Default"]=> NULL ["Tag"]=> NULL } ["WebAddr"]=> NULL ["OtherContactInfo"]=> NULL ["DefaultTaxCodeRef"]=> NULL ["Id"]=> string(4) "1361" ["SyncToken"]=> string(2) "28" ["MetaData"]=> object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPModificationMetaData)#87 (6) { ["CreatedByRef"]=> NULL ["CreateTime"]=> string(25) "2016-04-05T08:10:46-07:00" ["LastModifiedByRef"]=> NULL ["LastUpdatedTime"]=> string(25) "2020-02-11T09:08:12-08:00" ["LastChangedInQB"]=> NULL ["Synchronized"]=> NULL } ["CustomField"]=> NULL ["AttachableRef"]=> NULL ["domain"]=> NULL ["status"]=> NULL ["sparse"]=> NULL } }
 ],
```

Comment: Is that an array or an object with an array in it?

Comment: Try `$Customer->BillAddr['Line1']` the quotes are relevant round the assoc occurance

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried that and it didnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($Customer as $object) {
    echo $object->BillAddr->Line1 . "<br/>";
     echo $object->BillAddr->City . "<br/>";
    echo $object->SalesTermRef . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.